# 3D transform but using Canvas

Tags: css, html5-canvas

Trying to achieve something like this
http://attasi.com/labs/ipad/ which uses CSS transforms.

but using the Canvas object for greater compatibility.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: 1) The canvas allows you to draw things, per-pixel if need be 2) JavaScript has support for math. This implies that it is possible to do. Do you need more information?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [**three.js**](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/), it can render 3D using mainly WebGL, but it supports a subset of stuff with `<canvas>`, SVG and even the plain DOM - check [**this demo**](http://nulltask.github.com/sandbox/typographic-perfume/) that uses the DOM renderer.

[**Here**](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/#canvas) are demos using canvas. Some guy made [**this**](http://three.blackscorp.de/model/index.html) which shows it can do textured, animated game-like 3D with canvas.

Also, you may want to check out [a **particle engine**](https://github.com/zz85/sparks.js/wiki) and [a **tweening engine**](https://github.com/sole/tween.js) to go with that, plus [**stats**](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js) like FPS.